# Causes of Linux UDP packet drops

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, udp

I have a Linux C++ application which receives sequenced UDP packets.  Because of the sequencing, I can easily determine when a packet is lost or re-ordered, i.e. when a "gap" is encountered.  The system has a recovery mechanism to handle gaps, however, it is best to avoid gaps in the first place.  Using a simple libpcap-based packet sniffer, I have determined that there are no gaps in the data at the hardware level.  However, I am seeing a lot of gaps in my application.  This suggests the kernel is dropping packets; it is confirmed by looking at the **/proc/net/snmp** file.  When my application encounters a gap, the **Udp InErrors** counter increases.

At the system level, we have increased the max receive buffer:

```
# sysctl net.core.rmem_max
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
```

At the application level, we have increased the receive buffer size:

```
int sockbufsize = 33554432
int ret = setsockopt(my_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF,
        (char *)&sockbufsize,  (int)sizeof(sockbufsize));
// check return code
sockbufsize = 0;
ret = getsockopt(my_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, 
        (char*)&sockbufsize, &size);
// print sockbufsize
```

After the call to getsockopt(), the printed value is always 2x what it is set to (67108864 in the example above), but I believe that is to be expected.

I know that failure to consume data quickly enough can result in packet loss.  However, all this application does is check the sequencing, then push the data into a queue; the actual processing is done in another thread.  Furthermore, the machine is modern (dual Xeon X5560, 8 GB RAM) and very lightly loaded.  We have literally dozens of identical applications receiving data at a *much higher rate* that do not experience this problem.

Besides a too-slow consuming application, are there other reasons why the Linux kernel might drop UDP packets?

FWIW, this is on CentOS 4, with kernel 2.6.9-89.0.25.ELlargesmp.

Comment: Check your cabling, bit errors happens, especially if you wrap your cable around an eletrical noise source. Could be a buggy driver/nic, see if you can turn off/on checksum offloading. Keep in mind that network elements such as switches can drop packets. Monitor your traffic with wireshark and look for suspicious things. You might need to isntrument your app to verify you're not having excessive delays anywhere (e.g. waiting on a mutex for too long), so you're sure you're reading fast enough.

Comment: The pcap application confirmed that the NIC is receiving all packets, so it's not a wiring or switch issue.  As for the program itself, I'm using the exact same code shared by dozens of other applications.  This connection is the only one with the problem.

Comment: could the inbound checksums be incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my program. Its task is to receive udp packets in one thread and, using a blocking queue, write them to the database with another thread.

I noticed (using `vmstat 1`) that when the system was experiencing heavy I/O wait operations (reads) my application didn't receive packets, they were being received by the system though.

The problem was - when heavy I/O wait occured, the thread that was writing to the database was being I/O starved while holding the queue mutex. This way the udp buffer was being overflown by incoming packets, because main thread that was receiving them was hanging on the `pthred_mutex_lock()`.

I resolved it by playing with ioniceness (`ionice` command) of my process and the database process. Changing I/O sched class to Best Effort helped. Surprisingly I'm not able to reproduce this problem now even with default I/O niceness. 
My kernel is 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64.

I'm still developing this app so I'll try to update my post once I know more.

Answer (score 9):

If you have more threads than cores and equal thread priority between them it is likely that the receiving thread is starved for time to flush the incoming buffer.  Consider running that thread at a higher priority level than the others.

Similarly, although often less productive is to bind the thread for receiving to one core so that you do not suffer overheads of switching between cores and associated cache flushes.

Comment: It really does sound like the read thread is getting starved here. It could be other processes in the system contributing to the starvation though.

Comment: Just to clarify: by "flush the incoming buffer" do you simply mean keeping up with the rate of incoming messages, or there something more subtle?

Comment: @aix: yes, basically read everything available on the socket.

Comment: If you run `top` and type `1` to enable per-CPU display, do any CPUs/cores show 0% idle time?  If so, then receiving thread starvation is likely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`int ret = setsockopt(my_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&sockbufsize,  (int)sizeof(sockbufsize));`

First of all, `setsockopt` takes (int, int, int, void *, socklen_t), so there are no casts required.

> Using a simple libpcap-based packet sniffer, I have determined that there are no gaps in the data at the hardware level. However, I am seeing a lot of gaps in my application. This suggests the kernel is dropping packets;

It suggests that your environment is not fast enough. Packet capturing is known to be processing intensive, and you will observe that the global rate of transmissions on an interface will drop as you start capturing programs such as iptraf-ng or tcpdump on one.

Comment: He could be capturing from a different machine, though.

Comment: I was running the pcap program on the same machine as the application.  However, the drops occur regardless of whether or not the sniffer is running.  In other words, even without the sniffer running, my application logs gaps, and the /proc/net/snmp Udp InErrors counter increments.  (Before I used the sniffer, I wasn't aware of the /proc/net/snmp file.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't enough reputation to comment, but similar to @racic, I had a program where I had one receive thread, and one processing thread with a blocking queue between them.  I noticed the same issue with dropping packets because the receiving thread was waiting for a lock on the blocking queue.

To resolve this I added a smaller local buffer to the receiving thread, and had it only push data into the buffer then it wasn't locked (using std::mutex::try_lock).